# Вставить изображение в jsp или html, сервлет

Tags: java, servlet

Пользуюсь maven. С сервлетами работал мало и соответствующий результат. Нужно вывести изображение в качестве фона на jsp страничку. Проблема в том что при просмотре html кода страницы, браузер выводит изображение не найдено.
В интернете нашел способ подгрузить изображение в сервлет с помощью кода, изображение действительно выводится, но занимает всю страницу, которая генерируется автоматически и никак не связано с jsp. Не подскажите, где надо расположить изображение и как его приобщить к проекту чтобы в тегах html или jsp можно было вставить изображение.

сервлет

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        ////  processRequest(request, response);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("mypage.jsp").forward(request, response);


    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doPost(request, response);
        ///processRequest(request, response);

    }
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("image/png");
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        try {
            URL imageURL = Servlet.class.getResource("/fon1.png");
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(imageURL);
            ImageIO.setUseCache(false);
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", out);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <groupId>one</groupId>
    <artifactId>Registracia</artifactId>
    <version>3</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <!--  <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>Dir</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>src/main/resources/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: как именно вы разворачиваете приложение на сервер?

Comment: Приложение разворачивается с помощью glassfish

Comment: как именно вы это делаете?

Comment: в glassfish -> Application -> Deploy -> выберите файл -> servlet.war

Comment: добавьте pom.xml в вопрос

Comment: добавил pom.xml

Comment: Форматируйте код с помощью отступов в 4 пробела, также вы можете выделить отрывок кода в сообщении и нажать сочетание Ctrl+K, чтобы добавить или удалить отступ.

Answer (score 1):

Почему тебе нужно получить изображение именно в сервлете? Если папка с изображениями не находится внутри WEB-INF, то получить доступ к изображению можно напрямую из jsp:
Сервлет:

```
    public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/my.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<html>
<body>
    Hello world!
    <img src="images/russian_life.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Если же папка с изображениями лежит внутри WEB-INF или изображение находится в БД, то получить к нему доступ можно только через сервлет. Тогда ты загружаешь изображение в сервлет,  который просто в OutputStream пишет все изображение и ставит правильный Content-Type.
На jsp странице используешь тег `<img src=«/path/to/serlvet»/>`

Comment: Извините очень мало работал с сервлетами. По поводу первого способа. Где именно в проекте maven должна лежать папка с изображениями, чтобы получить доступ напрямую из jsp. Есть несколько мест куда можно положить, в webapp или в ресурсы. При размещении в этих папках браузер изображения не видит. По поводу второго, вы не могли бы уточнить каким методом или способом загрузить изображение в сервлет. И еще момент «/path/to/serlvet»/ - это константа или нужно подставлять значения

Comment: Если изображение лежит в webapps, то jsp должен его увидеть(за исключением WEB-INF/images). Обрати внимание какой ты указываешь путь: абсолютный или относительный. Очень часто из-за этого возникают ошибки. Далее. Очевидно что вместо path/to/servlet нужно подставить реальный url адрес к сервлету. Как из сервлета передать изображение клиенту смотри в отдельном вопросе.